# Always visible scroll bar in ListView and DataGridView in Winform Framework 2.0

Tags: winforms, listview, datagridview

Can any one provide solution to display scrollbar always (even there is no item in list) in DataGridView and ListView in Winform (Framwwork 2.0)?

I tried but not found anywhere.

I tried below function but not worked as expected

```
[DllImport("user32")] 
private static extern long ShowScrollBar(long hwnd, long wBar, long bShow);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) (it's a freeware 3rd party WinForms control):

```
listView.VScrollBarDisplayMode = BetterListViewScrollBarDisplayMode.ShowAlways;
```

the same can be done for horizontal scroll bar:

```
listView.HScrollBarDisplayMode = BetterListViewScrollBarDisplayMode.ShowAlways;
```

The control is 100% managed, so no WinAPI calls are necessary there.